# Python Schema Or()

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, schema

I was wondering if anyone has used the pypi module Schema and could help me?

So I have a [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) which I want to validate and I'm using the Or method which is nice because it allows you to have either or option.  However what I didn't realise till after is that allows all in the option not just one.

For example:

```py
from schema import Schema, Or
test_schema = Schema({Or("fist", "schema"): str, "second": int})
test_validate = {"first": "test", "schema": "check", "second": 15}
test_schema.validate(test_validate)
{"first": "test", "schema": "check", "second": 15}
```

From the module, this is the expected outcome, however I was wondering if there was a way to enforce to **only** choose one and not both.  From the docs I just can't see it.  If anyone knows how to do this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess I have some learning to do with regards to reading docs.  So in the schema docs for Or they have an only_one option but I was unsure how this works however it seems that you need to specify it as an argument when you're calling or for it to work.

```py
from schema import Schema, Or
test_schema = Schema({Or("fist", "schema", only_one=True): str, "second": int})
test_validate = {"first": "test", "schema": "check", "second": 15}
```

Then I'll get a error raised saying multiple keys are present.  I'll take this as a lesson learned that I still have al ot to learn in about programming documentation even though I've been doing this off and on for about over 2 years now :).